# Creating a filter in mongo-go-driver for .FindOne

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to check a collection to see if there is at least one documents that match a specific set of values.

I've tried reading the documentation at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#usage, but I can't seem to find much help there. I'm pretty new to MongoDB & Go, I believe that this is more a problem of my lack of experience.

Here is a sample query from Studio 3T that I'm trying to run with mongo-go-driver:

```
db.getCollection("events").find(
    { 
        "event.eventType" : "OSR", 
        "context.vehicleId" : NumberInt(919514), 
        "ts" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2019-06-21T21:38:43.022+0000")
        }
    }
).limit(1);
```

It seems that the `context.FindOne` method will do what I want (and eliminating the need for the `.limit(1)`). I thought that it would be straight forward to "port" this to Go and the mongo-go-driver.

I can sort of make this work, for example I have the following which will find me all the OSR:

```golang
var query = &bson.D{
        {"event.eventType", "OSR"},
    }

result := bson.D{}
e := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), query).Decode(&result)
```

This will return me one document. Now, if I want to include the `vehicleId` value, and I update the `query` to:

```golang
var query = &bson.D{
        {"event.eventType", "OSR"},
        {"context.vehicleId", 919514}, 
    }
```

No documents are returned. I haven't bother to expand `query` to include the `ts` field yet.

I would expect at to still have at least one document returned, but nothing is showing up.  Does anybody have some tips, suggestions or guidance on what I'm doing wrong (or perhaps how I can do this better)?

Comment: your code works, are u sure u on the right db and collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure, but have you tried with `bson.M` instead of `bson.D`?

It seems like it's working for me at least.

```golang
query := &bson.M{
  "event.eventType": "OSR",
  "context.vehicleId": 919514, 
}
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M) for more information.

Also, like @owlwalks said, are you sure, you're in the right collection?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'll try with `bson.M` and hopefully that fixes things. 

I double checked, and I'm 100% certain I'm in the correct collection (thanks for the suggestion @owlwalks).

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes, @TomOpgenorth

Comment: Using `bson.M` worked.  We also found out that my query wasn't using the correct index, which resulted in it being super inefficient and incredibly slow.

Comment: from the docs, `bson.D` should be used only when order of the elements in the document is necessary.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/63855571587c4e7c7ba556410df182b3019208d6/bson/bson.go#L25